# Need to extract name value from json array of the output

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, json

I am unable to extract the name variable from the graph output of the following react code. trying to store the name value from the json output received from the api in my state variable in React. How do i do it?

```
state = {
        auth: false,
        username: '',
        access_token: '',
        app_name: [],
    };

    responseFacebook = response => {
        {/*console.log(response);*/}
        if(response.status !== 'unknown')
        this.setState({
            auth: true,
            username: response.name,
            access_token: response.accessToken
        });
        graph.setAccessToken(this.state.access_token);
        graph.get("/me/accounts", function(err, res) {
            let response = res;
            console.log(response.data[0]);
          });
        console.log(this.state);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because your checking the second `console.log` outside the callback. In javascript the callbacks( the function inside the get call ) are trigerred later, when the API completes, hence you will not get anything in the `console.log` outside the callback, if you rewrite your example it might work.

```
state = {
    auth: false,
    username: '',
    access_token: '',
    app_name: [],
};

responseFacebook = response => {
    if(response.status !== 'unknown') {
        this.setState({
            auth: true,
            username: response.name,
            access_token: response.accessToken
        });
        graph.setAccessToken(this.state.access_token);
        graph.get("/me/accounts", (err, res) => {
            let response = res;
            this.setState({username:response.data[0]});
            console.log(this.state);
        });
    }
}
```

[Event loop reference](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

Comment: I tried but i am getting the following error



TypeError: this.setState is not a function
Graph.callback
src/reusable/Facebook.js:31
  28 |     graph.setAccessToken(this.state.access_token);
  29 |     graph.get("/me/accounts", function(err, res) {
  30 |         let response = res;
> 31 |         this.setState({app_name:response.data[0]});
     | ^  32 |         console.log(this.state);
  33 |       });
  34 | }

Comment: @JothicharanJothibabu changed normal function to arrow function so that this will refer to parent scope, could you please check with this change?

Comment: hey. it works. Thank you so much

Comment: @JothicharanJothibabu You're welcome, do checkout the difference between arrow functions and normal function differences (scopes) :)

Comment: Will do. Thank you once again! :)